# php array grouping

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have this array:

```
array{
  0 => string '1' (length=1) 
  1 => string '18' (length=2)
  2 => string '18' (length=2)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => string '1' (length=1)
  6 => string '1' (length=1)
  7 => string '1' (length=1)
  8 => string '18' (length=2)
  9 => string '18' (length=2)
}
```

I want to make it looks like this:

```
array{
  0 => array (
          0 => '1'
             )
  1 => array (
          0 => '18' 
          1 => '18' 
             )
  2 => array (
          0 => '1'
          1 => '1'
          2 => '1'
          3 => '1'
          4 => '1'
          5 => '1' 
             )
  3 => array (
          0 => '18'
          1 => '18' 
             )
}
```

So the idea is, i want to group the array by finding if the next array key is the same as the current key, if the next array key is the same as the current one, it merges it inside a new array, like grouping.

i couldn't really find an answer here, or on google, the idea is there is key 1 then 2 the 1 again, i want to group the similar keys until a different key comes in, the key (2) broke the grouping and started a new group, then broke by key 1 to start a new group as well,

the idea is for chatting messages, facebook and msn they group the messages by the user who sent them, untill another user comes in and break the group.
but can't find out how.

Thanks

Comment: i tried using Next n prev n curr, that if next(array)->sender == curr(array)->sender... but couldn't think logicaly after this step.
  $ress = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i<count($results); $i++){
   if($results[$i]->sender == @$results[$i-1]->sender){
    $ress[$i][] = $results[$i]->sender;
    $ress[$i][] = $results[$i-1]->sender;
   }else{
    $ress[$i] = $results[$i]->sender;
   }
  }
  var_dump($ress);
that's the for i test i did.

Comment: Think facebook chat and msn, they group message by the sender, until another sender appears, it breaks the group.

Comment: okay i updated the array example, please note there's an extra array, ignore that i needed to show this to @nickb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to loop it yourself, finding the blocks where the current element `$i` matches the next element `$j`, continuing to increment `$j` while the equality holds, and then slicing that section off into its own array with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$new = array(); $count = count( $old) - 1;
for( $i = 0, $j = 1; $i < $count; $i = $j, $j = $i + 1) {
    while( $old[$i] === $old[$j]) $j++;
    $new[] = array_slice( $old, $i, $j - $i);
}
```

This [will print](http://codepad.org/1CJAcqQX):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 18
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 18
        )

)
```

Comment: this is giving me an endless loop, if i put it like :

  $new = array(); $count = count( $results) - 1;
  for( $i = 0, $j = 1; $i < $count; $i = $j, $j = $i + 1) {
   while( $results[$i] === $results[$j]) $j++;
   $new[] = array_slice( $results, $i, $j - $i);
  }

Comment: the returned data from the database are stored in $results

Comment: @Emad - It works in my test, as you can see above. Renaming the array to `$results` and copy/pasting the code from your comment, [it still works](http://codepad.org/N2i7yVO2).

Comment: okay, fixed the array keys in my code. now works, but not grouping at all, how can i style post a styled array here, if i copy/paste it here it looks crappy.

Comment: i upadeted the question, now it has the output after your suggestion, the original result has doesnt have a child array.

Comment: it worked! thanks, i updated the code, added to ur loop (while) $results[$i] '->sender', but it has an error which will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

untested because you didn't provide copy/paste sample input.

```
$prev = current($arr);
$grp = array();
$res = array();
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    if ($v === $prev) {
        $grp[] = $v;
    } else {
        $res[] = $grp;
        $grp = array();
    }
    $prev = $v;
}
```

Comment: @Emad you'll get better replies if you show the output of echo var_export($your_array); which can be copy/pasted.

Comment: the array is too big, it worked somehow, but still adding extra uneeded keys.

Comment: but again, think facebook chat, lets say they have array of the messages items, for sure they have inside each array an element which refers to the sender(sender_id=xxx), so they probably regroup the messages, by the sender untill the next array key has a different sender, it breaks the grouping, and open a new group...etc